# how to resolve file in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

With angular stats we can load file like this:

```
    .state('app.dashboard.v1', {
        url: '/v1',
        templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Dashboard v1' },
        resolve: {
            service: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    serie: true,
                    files: [
                        'assets/plugins/jquery-jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css',
                        'assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css',
                        'assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css',
                         ...
                        'assets/plugins/jquery-jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js',
                        'assets/plugins/jquery-jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js',
                        'assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
                    ] 
                });
            }]
        }
    })
```

what if I'm using directive? how to make the similar approach?

```
app.directive('myAdminDashboardDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'Views/MyAccount/my_admin_dashboard.tpl.html'
        // such as: files: [...] (?)
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you even want to read javascript and css files into a directive?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship it just for convenient for file management. I don't want to put all CSS file in index.html, very hard to management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, we can use "AngularCSS" as plugin for the purpose. AgnularCSS can be grabbed from bower or github.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't. If you want to load a script file to use within your directive, you should consider loading it along side with your route every time your directive is used. An alternative could be write it on the same file that your directive is located.

Give us more detail then we could help you to choose a better strategy.

Comment: can you tell me detail on how route or directive "same file" works?

Comment: What does contains these files?